# Is there any way to pass information to the Commit function using SimpleXML?

Tags: java, simple-framework

I want to deserialize an object that contains filenames relative to the xml file.

I am trying to access the referenced files in the Commit function of the object but I have found no way to pass the path of the xml to the Commit function.

I could use a global but I don't like that idea.

I could use a filter and require the xml to use the filter option. This method isn't too bad but I would prefer not to. Another issue with this method is the need to 'unfilter' when serializing.

Answer (score 0):

During serialization a map can be used to gather information like so.

```
@Commit
public void commit(Map session) {
  String blah = session.get("xyz")
  session.put("abc", "foo");
}
```

Also you can pre-instantiate an object before serialization like so.

```
Foo foo = new Foo("my/path");
Persister persister = new Persister();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("my/path");
persister.read(foo, in);
```

Comment: In your first example I couldn't find a way to initialize that map. There is a map you can create the Persistor with but it doesn;t appear to be the same map that is passed to the commit.